# Emptying a grid in kendo UI after receiving erroneous data

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui

The kendoUI grid on which I am working on is refreshed when you pass new data with the datasource, which is fine, but I need to empty it when an error or an action occurs.

So, how can I empty and refresh the kendoUI grid manually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give this a try:

```
$("#yourGridId").empty(); // Empty the grid.
$("#yourGridId").data('kendoGrid').refresh(); // Refrsh the grid.
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had already tried the refresh(), but not the empty ().